# Django form subclass non-functional

Tags: python, django, forms, customization, registration

Here is a custom registration form inheriting from `[django-registration][1]`. My extra form fields do not appear and field cleaning methods do not run, something which I observe from the functionality and supported by the print statements (the `Custom form runs` print statement runs but not 'Custom Password clean'. Both the field appears and the validations run when placed into the original `django-registration` code, provided below.

Why is this happening?

```
my app/forms.py

from registration.forms import RegistrationForm

class CustomRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
"""
Form for registering a new user account.

Validates that the requested username is not already in use, and
requires the password to be entered twice to catch typos.

I have has added email uniqueness validation and minimum 
password length validation.

Subclasses should feel free to add any additional validation they
need, but should avoid defining a ``save()`` method -- the actual
saving of collected user data is delegated to the active
registration backend.

"""
print 'Custom form runs'
LOCALITIES = (
    ('1', 'London'),
    ('2', 'Berlin'),    
)
locality = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=LOCALITIES,
    label='Where are you?',
    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

def clean_password1(self):
    """
    Verify that password is longer than 5 characters.

    """
    print 'Custom Password clean'
    password = self.cleaned_data['password1']
    print 'custom valid'
    if len(password) < 6:
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("Password needs to be at least 6 characters long"))
    return password

def clean_email(self):
    """
    Validate that the supplied email address is unique for the site.

    """
    email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    if User.objects.filter(email__iexact=self.cleaned_data['email']):
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("This email address is already in use. \
            Please supply a different email address."))
    return email
```

django-registration

`registration/forms.py`

```
"""
Forms and validation code for user registration.

Note that all of these forms assume Django's bundle default ``User``
model; since it's not possible for a form to anticipate in advance the
needs of custom user models, you will need to write your own forms if
you're using a custom model.

"""

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
"""
Form for registering a new user account.

Validates that the requested username is not already in use, and
requires the password to be entered twice to catch typos.

Subclasses should feel free to add any additional validation they
need, but should avoid defining a ``save()`` method -- the actual
saving of collected user data is delegated to the active
registration backend.

"""
required_css_class = 'required'

username = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^[\w.@+-]+$',
                            max_length=30,
                            label=_("Username"),
                            error_messages={'invalid': _("This value may contain only letters, numbers and @/./+/-/_ characters.")})
email = forms.EmailField(label=_("E-mail"))
password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                            label=_("Password"))
password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                            label=_("Password (again)"))



def clean_username(self):
    """
    Validate that the username is alphanumeric and is not already
    in use.

    """
    existing = User.objects.filter(username__iexact=self.cleaned_data['username'])
    if existing.exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("A user with that username already exists."))
    else:
        return self.cleaned_data['username']


def clean_email(self):
    """
    Validate that the supplied email address is unique for the site.

    """
    email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    if User.objects.filter(email__iexact=self.cleaned_data['email']):
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("This email address is already in use. \
            Please supply a different email address."))
    return email

def clean(self):
    """
    Verify that the values entered into the two password fields
    match. Note that an error here will end up in
    ``non_field_errors()`` because it doesn't apply to a single
    field.

    """
    if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data and 'password2' in self.cleaned_data:
        if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("The two password fields didn't match."))
    return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: "Custom form runs" will print when the form is first imported. But where are you actually using the form?

Comment: I use the form with django-registration. So in `urls.py`:     `from crewcal.forms import CustomRegistrationForm
url(r'^register/$', 'RegistrationView',
    {'form_class':CustomRegistrationForm,
        'backend':'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend' }, name='registration_register'),`

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you customise a class based view. The third parameter in a urlconf is for parameters that are passed as part of the request, alongside those captured from the URL itself: it's not for configuring the class view.

To do that, you should either override the class in your code and set the attributes there, or you can pass them as parameters to the class's `as_view()` method:

```
url(r'^register/$', RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=CustomRegistrationForm, backend=registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend), name='registration_register'),
```